# Session Variable display wrong value inside iframe

Tags: php

I have a problem with my index.php. I have a form that will be submitted on compute.php, where compute echoes the value of the session variable inside an iframe  in index.php. Here's my codes:

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function reply_click(){
document.getElementById('iframe').src=('compute.php');
}
</script>

<? session_start(); ?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"  
onSubmit="reply_click(); return false"> 
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 width=320 border="0">
<tr><td>
<button type='submit' id='1' name='form_submit'>Compute</button> 
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['form_submit']))
    { 
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['val']="8";
    }
?>  
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

compute.php

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$val=$_SESSION['val'];
echo($val);

?>
```

As you can see in my codes, whenever the form is submitted the session variable is initialized to 8. And iframe src will be compute.php, which is supposedly displaying 8. But the problem is the iframe displays nothing. Is something wrong with my onSubmit event? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need the second `session_start()` after the `isset($_POST['form_submit'])`.

Second, you need to move the first `session_start()` all the way to the top **before any output to the browser** like the javascript.

Like:

```
<? session_start(); ?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=10 width=320 border="0">
<tr><td>
<button type='submit' id='1' name='form_submit'>Compute</button>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['form_submit'])) {
   $_SESSION['val']="8";
}
?>

<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['form_submit'])) {
    // drop out of php and echo the javascript
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('iframe').src=('compute.php');
</script>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've tried this code, but compute.php returns a value of 1 instead of 8. And it's not showed on the iframe. It's only shown when I manually type the url to load  compute.php.

Comment: I tested it and see you have a timing problem with your onSubmit javascript. This gets executed **before** the post thus showing an old value. I changed the code to work around that. You don't need the onSubmit and change the iframe if there was a POST. It would be easier to always show compute.php with `<iframe src=compute.php>` and check in compute.php if the SESSION variable 'var' is set.

Answer (score 0):

Your "return false" in your form's onSubmit function means that your form is never being submitted and therefore your session value is never set.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that:

```
if(isset($_POST['form_submit']))
```

will never be true. When you click on the button, you set the iframe to the correct URL, but you say `return false;` to prevent the page from reloading. But this also prevents any post requests from happening. So $_POST is never set.